# Ruby remove nil values from array with .reject

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
scores = [1, 2, 3, "", 4]
```

And I want to remove all blank values. But when I run this:

```
puts scores.reject(&:empty?)
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `empty' for 1:Fixnum
```

How can I remove values that are not integers from my array in a one step process? I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: How are you building the array in the first place to have either integers or empty strings? Seems like a strange combination to me...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
scores.grep(Integer)
```

Note that if you plan to map the values, you can do that in a block after:

```
scores.grep(Integer){|x| x+1 }
```

Bonus if you want to do the same thing, but your numbers are strings:

```
scores.grep(/\d+/){|x|x.to_i}
```

Comment: Grep is using the case equality operator (===), and I think that call is_a?

Comment: More info on the case-equality and classes here: http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/qt/On-Case-And-Class.htm

Comment: You should use `Integer`, not `Fixnum`

Comment: Correct, changed original post.

Answer (score 55):

To reject only `nil` would be:

`array.compact`

Answer (score 21):

If you want to remove blank values, you should use `blank?`: (requires Rails / ActiveSupport)

```
scores.reject(&:blank?)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`""`, `" "`, `false`, `nil`, `[]`, and `{}` are blank.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
scores.select{|e| e.is_a? Integer}
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need reject `nil` only, so it can be done like this:

```
scores.reject(&:nil?)
```

Comment: this is equivalent to scores.compact

Answer (score 1):

```
scores = [1, 2, 3, "", 4, nil]
scores.reject{|s| s.to_s == ''}
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me

```
scores.reject!{|x| x.to_s.empty?}
```

Comment: don't use bang method, if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores.select{|score| score.is_a? Fixnum}
```

or, as Fixnum inherits from Integer, you can also go for

```
scores.select{|score| score.is_a? Integer)
```

...if that seems more descriptive.

Array and Enumerable tend to offer many ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`&:empty?` will work for hashes, arrays, and strings, but not numbers. The method you use in reject must be valid for all items in a list. `&:blank?` will work fine for this reason.